# Addressing "WebLogic server side components must use AQ JMS datasource configuration"

Tags: java, oracle, jms, weblogic11g, advanced-queuing

I'm migrating an old Java application, originally written for Oracle Application Server, to WebLogic 10.3.6 in Oracle Fusion Middleware. The application uses Oracle Advanced Queue / JMS functionality. The AQ is already configured in a database. Now that the application is running in WebLogic when I reach the AQ code I see this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WebLogic server side components must use AQ JMS datasource configuration
```

I have been reading turgid Oracle documentation for over 8 hours now and I still have no idea how I'm supposed to address this. I believe the error message is telling me I need to use WebLogic's in-built JMS connections to talk to the database's AQ but when I try to understand how to achieve this I'm just going round in circles.

When I googled the error message I found [this](http://www.programmingforliving.com/2010/10/javalangunsupportedoperationexception.html) suggesting I put my old aqapi.jar at the beginning of the server node's classpath. I did this but to no effect.

Is it actually necessary for me to change the way I connect to the AQ, using the WebLogic approach, or can I make a relatively simple change and continue using the existing approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the answer was yes, I did need to change the way I connected to AQ. I never saw any explanation of why this was different in WebLogic or what the benefits were in doing it this way. Although the WebLogic documentation was very confusing and fairly useless for actually making configuration changes I was eventually directed to the following very useful Oracle blog posts.

[How to Create a Simple JMS Queue in Weblogic Server 11g](https://blogs.oracle.com/fusionmiddlewaresupport/jms-step-1-how-to-create-a-simple-jms-queue-in-weblogic-server-11g-v2)
and
[How to Set Up an AQ JMS (Advanced Queueing JMS) for SOA Purposes](https://blogs.oracle.com/fusionmiddlewaresupport/jms-step-6-how-to-set-up-an-aq-jms-advanced-queueing-jms-for-soa-purposes-v2)